# .NET MAUI: How to develop .NET MAUI hybrid app for wear OS?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

This question may sound too generic,
but How to develop .NET MAUI hybrid app for wear OS?

I want to develop app for android wear OS watch using .NET MAUI and blazor,
it will be good for me if there any pointers or samples provided?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/1144

Comment: [OPINION] Just don't. For a limited-power-cpu-ram device, it is more appropriate to write device-specific code, not cross-platform code. Then the question becomes "Does .Net 7+ support wear OS?" Which isn't a question for StackOverflow; its a question for the .Net roadmap, or an issue to raise at .Net github issues.